# MYSQL COUNT HAVING Issue

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, having

I have 2 tables a forum topic table and forum comments.

I am trying to get a list of all forum topics with a count of how many comments are in each topic.

The comments table contains the PK of the forum topic for each topic.

I have tried

```
SELECT
  `forum_topics`.`topic_id`,
  `forum_topics`.`topic_name`,
  `forum_topics`.`topic_info`, 
  `forum_topics`.`topic_img`,
  `forum_topics`.`creation_date`,
  `forum_topics`.`is_deleted`
FROM
  `forum_topics`
JOIN
  `forum_comments`
ON
  `forum_comments`.`topic_id` = `forum_topics`.`topic_id`
GROUP BY
  `forum_topics`.`topic_id`
HAVING
  COUNT(`forum_comments`.`comment_id`) >= 0
  AND `forum_topics`.`review_status` = 'reviewed';
```

This does not seem to return any results but also no errors

Hope someone can help

Comment: Example of your database structure?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your query. Are you sure that you have some records in `forum_comments` with the right `topic_id`?

Comment: Are you sure the status is correct?

Comment: Not an answer, but some observations: the `HAVING COUNT` condition should be unnecessary, as you have inner joined to `forum_comments`, while the `review_status = 'reviewed'` condition should be in the `where` clause, not the `having` clause; not only that, but if you want **all** topics (not just all **reviewed** topics) you should probably remove that condition anyway.

Comment: I do not yet have any comments hence why i tried >= 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT forum_topics.topic_id, forum_topics.topic_name, forum_topics.topic_info, 
   forum_topics.topic_img, forum_topics.creation_date, forum_topics.is_deleted
FROM forum_topics 
JOIN forum_comments ON forum_comments.topic_id = forum_topics.topic_id 
WHERE forum_topics.review_status = 'reviewed'
GROUP BY forum_topics.topic_id
HAVING COUNT(forum_comments.comment_id) >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems LEFT JOIN fixed it. I have given you a tick because i understand your query more. Marks answer is also correct

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  `forum_topics`.`topic_id`,
  `forum_topics`.`topic_name`,
  `forum_topics`.`topic_info`, 
  `forum_topics`.`topic_img`,
  `forum_topics`.`creation_date`,
  `forum_topics`.`is_deleted`,
  `forum_topics`.`review_status`,
  COUNT(`forum_comments`.`comment_id`) count_comments
FROM
  `forum_topics`
LEFT JOIN
  `forum_comments`
ON
  `forum_comments`.`topic_id` = `forum_topics`.`topic_id`
order by case when `forum_topics`.`review_status` = 'reviewed' then 1 else 2 end, 
         count_comments desc
```